# Is the content of a predicate in c++ wait_for method mutex protected or not?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, predicate

Suppose, *countMe* is a global variable and I am launching 10 threads at the same time to this while loop, is the variable *countMe* mutex protected in the predicate?
I think because when the code reaches to the wait_for it unlocks and releases the lock, the variable countMe isn't mutex protected. Am I right?

```cpp
while (true)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx_kill);
    cv_kill.wait_for(lock, 500ms, [&]() {++countMe; return killFlag; });

    if (killFlag)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I right?

Nope, you're wrong.

> I think because when the code reaches to the wait_for it unlocks the
> lock, the variable countMe isn't mutext protected.

No, the mutex is in a locked state when the lambda gets evaluated. Guaranteed.

cppreference.com [describes the predicate version of `wait_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_for) in terms of `wait_until`, [which is described as follows](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait_until):

```
while (!stop_waiting()) {
    if (wait_until(lock, timeout_time) == std::cv_status::timeout) {
        return stop_waiting();
    }
}
```

Note that the initial state of the mutex is that it's locked. The predicate, called "stop_waiting" here, is always called when the mutex is in the locked state.

You can think of `wait_for` as just a predicate-less `wait`, with the additional predicate check as a discrete, separate step. After `wait` returns the mutex gets relocked, and that happens before the predicate, your lambda, executes. If it votes thumbs down the mutex gets, once again, atomically unlocked together with the condition variable getting waited on again.

P.S. The above discussion presumes that your `countMe` is always accessed, elsewhere, with the same lock being held. This is presumed by your question, but merely formally noted.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Should there be something like 'std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);' before that while loop and also should it be 'cv_m.wait_unitl(lock, timeout_time) == std::cv_status::timeout)'?

Comment: Well, whether there should or should not be is something that requires a complete understanding of not just this execution thread but all other execution threads' logic that's not shown here.This will, obviously, change the scope of the locking. Whether the resulting logical changes are what they should be, that's something that you'll need to figure out.